# How to schedule async task in a more controlled way to save network usage

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an async task in one of my fragments. Whenever the fragment becomes visible, the async task runs and `onPostExecute` method displays the data when it's done.

The problem is when every time the fragment becomes visible, the async task runs and it takes 2~3 seconds, and every time the progress spinner gets displayed. That's annoying.

Can I schedule the async task to

1. run it only when the fragment is visible for the first time (every "first time" when the fragment is visible after restarting the app, not just when the app is installed for the first time)
2. In every 10~20 minutes (or in a definite time interval) to refresh data
3. when the refresh button is pressed

How can I save my network usage from that async task?

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
            recyclerView.getItemAnimator().setChangeDuration(0);
            recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new 
GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), mNoOfColumns));
            adapterDod = new AdapterDotd(getActivity(), data);
            adapterDod.notifyDataSetChanged();

            if (AsyncTaskCount == AsyncTaskRequested) {
                lottieAnimationView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            recyclerView.invalidate();
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterDod);
    }
```

Comment: save time in `sharedpreferences` as `lastUpdateTime` when you first fetch the data. Every time the `fragment` becomes visible, get time from `sharedpreferences`, check if `(currentTime - lastUpdateTime) > 10min` then only refresh data.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to record and check the time of last updated inside `onPostExecute`. Store it somewhere(variable, SharedPreferences, DB, etc.)

Second, you will need a flag that records if the given fragment has shown to the user once, after the app is run.

After these, if I understood your intention correctly, add a hook on the fragment to detect if the fragment is visible, if it's visible and visible for the first time, check your last updated timestamp. If the time has elapsed well enough, trigger that async task.

Add a separate event listener on the button to also manually trigger the async task on button click event.

If you also want to execute the async task every time when certain time diff of (current and the last updated) is reached, create a timer task that runs in the background to make it regularly checks for the timestamp of last updated, and check if the time diff has reached the expected amount, trigger the async task if true.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Architecture Components https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture
And save your self the headaches of managing lifecyle. Especially using the ViewModel and LifeData Components.

In view model

```
public class MyViewModel extends ViewModel {
  private MutableLiveData<List<Items>> itemsLiveData = new MutableLiveData();

    public void fetchDataFromNetwork() {
       .......
      startAsynWork()
    }

    .......
    onPostExecute(....) {
        itemsLiveData.setValue(data);
    }

    // Return a live data that will be observed in the fragment
    public LiveData<List<Items>> getItems() {
       return itemsLiveData;
    }

}
```

Then in Fragment

```
private MyViewModel viewModel;
onCreate(....) {
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel.class);
    // Make network request here. It won't be repeated every time fragment is visible, only when it's created or recreated
    viewModel.fetchDataFromNetwork();
}

onCreateView(....) {

 .......
    viewModel.getItems().observe(this, items -> {
         updateUi(items)
    }
}
```